# QGIS 3.4 - Extract Z - Vector Geometry

Tags: qgis-3, vector, extract

In QGIS Versions before 3.4 there was a tool called "Extract-Z" values (Not drape!) in the Vector Geometry Toolbox...

Anybody know where it has gone?

I have not found it, neither in the  processing toolbox nor in the vector tools...

Comment: There is "Extract Z Values" tool in QGIS verisons after 3.4 (I have 3.8, 3.12 in Windows)

Comment: I know, but I was hoping to be able to use it in 3.4 also...

Comment: @S.Kasanmascheff - If you go to the `Save As...` option or similar for the layer, is there an `Include z-dimension` option?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes there is.... Simply seems to be not there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my question seems to be: There is not Extract-z tool in QGIS 3.4